# What's the best way to read .tiff geospatial files for online applications?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, geospatial, tiff, geoserver

So I have an Azure Blob Storage set up, which is connected to my backend. Frontend (React) calls my API to upload .tiff geospatial large files (1024+ MB each) and long story short the file ends up in the desired container in Azure Blob Storage. The issue I have is when I need to display that file in React, since the file is too large it won't load unless I add some sort of web caching along with that. I tried GeoServer and I think that might work but I've been running into some issues connecting Azure Blob Storage with it. What do you think is the best way to move forward with this?

Comment: Look for adding overviews or pyramids and then read up on cloud optimized geotiffs. Gdal is your friend